# CancellationToken: почему структура?

Tags: c#, tpl, task

Почему `CancellationToken` реализован как структура?
Ведь структура является типом значения, как тогда реализован данный механизм?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = cancelTokenSource.Token;

    Task task1 = new Task(() => Factorial(5, token));
    task1.Start();

    cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
}

static void Factorial(int x, CancellationToken token)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Операция прервана токеном");
            return;
        }

        result *= i;
        Console.WriteLine("Факториал числа {0} равен {1}", i, result);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Ведь структура является типом значения и создается копия объекта при передачи параметра `CancellationToken token`

Comment: в этой структуре есть ссылка на содержащий ее `CancellationTokenSource`, который является классом, и по сути все вызовы обращаются внутри к нему

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Почему `CancellationToken` реализован как структура?

Для борьбы за эффективность.

В большинстве случаев, да, `CancellationToken` вполне мог бы быть и классом, одна аллокация ничего не меняет, так как многопоточный код обычно некритичен к паре лишних мелких аллокаций.

Но ведь `CancellationToken` задумывался как общий механизм отмены. И существуют случаи, в которых аллокации критичны для пользователей. Если бы `CancellationToken` был классом, то в этих случаях пользователям фреймворка проходилось бы пользоваться самописной структурой, и, хуже того, они не смогли бы пользоваться библиотечными методами.

(Например, если пользователь хочет в метод, который ожидает `CancellationToken`, передать `CancellationToken.None`, потому что ему нужна скорость и не нужна отмена.)

Так что разработчики решили облегчить нам, пользователям, жизнь, и сделали `CancellationToken` таки структурой.

---

По поводу реализации механизма: да, разработчики нарушили семантику, и `CancellationToken` ведёт себя как типичный класс, а не как типичная структура. Они реализовали это таким образом. В `CancellationToken` есть единственное поле `private CancellationTokenSource m_source;` ([ссылка на исходники](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationToken.cs)). В проверке на равенство сравнивается `m_source`, и при копировании `m_source` копируется тоже, так что копия токена *ведёт себя* как оригинал, и тем самым неотличима от него. В частности, если оригинал токена отменён, то его копия — тоже.

Comment: да, понял. То есть причина только в выделении памяти под объект? То, что структура храниться в стеке, и так будет эффективнее?

Comment: @khirnick: Ну да. Если у вас метод, в котором создаётся `CancellationToken`, вызывается десятки тысяч раз в секунду, то это позволяет уменьшить нагрузку на сборщик мусора, т. к. токены не нужно будет собирать.